# What Bottom Bracket for a 2007 Rush Hour frame?

Tags: bottom-bracket

The stock rush hour bottom bracket is a FSA BB-7420.  Would a Shimano BB-UN54 that is 68 X 107mm work in that frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame is almost certainly a 68mm English-threaded shell.  Beyond that, the cranks you're using and the desired chainline determine the bottom bracket spindle length.

If the rest of the bike is stock, [BikePedia](http://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?Year=2007&Brand=Raleigh&Model=Rush+Hour&Type=bike) claims that the crankset is a TruVativ Touro Track. The [Truvativ Crankset](http://files.dahon.com/support/manuals/2009/components/truvativ_5_arm_crankset.pdf) docs specify a 108mm bottom bracket with that crankset giving you a 43.5mm chainline. Reducing that by a half millimeter or so by switching to a 107mm bottom bracket should be just fine.